# Regex for mass replacement of tuple syntax to export const in JavaScript

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, storybook

I have lots of files that have a tuple syntax which I want to rewrite to upgrade to the latest storybook. The files look like this:

```
['AcknowledgementsSection', () => <AcknowledgementsSection />],
['AuthorizedUserSection', () => <AuthorizedUserSectionWithStore />],
['AuthorizedUserAlert', () => <AuthorizedUserAlert />],
```

I want to do a global search and replace in VS Code so that the output looks like this:

```
export const acknowledgementsSection = () => <AcknowledgementsSection />;
export const authorizedSection = () => <AuthorizedSectionWithStore />;
export const authorizedAlert = () => <AuthorizedAlert />;
```

Here's what I'm trying so far:

`\[('.*'), \(\) => (.*),`

How could I use this in VS code to replace everything correctly?

**Update post accepted answer**

Edge case I have is

```
['Decline Modal', () => <DeclineModal />],
```

and need to concatenate the capture group

```
export const declineModal = () => <DeclineModal />;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make the match a bit more specific, and then use `\l` before the first capturing group in the replacement.

Search

```
\['([^']*)', (\(\) => <[^<>]*>)\],
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ySIeJ8/1)

Replace

```
export const \l$1 $2;
```

The pattern matches

- `\['` Match `['`
- `([^']*)` Capture in **group 1** matching any char except `'` or a newline
- `',`  Match a comma and space
- `(` Capture group 2

  - `\(\) => <[^<>]*>` Match `() =>`  followed by matching from `<` till `>`
- `)` Close **group 2**
- `\],` Match `],`

[image]

Comment: Just a fun fact: in VS Code, you do not need `\r\n` in the negated character class. `[^']` does not match line break chars. `\['([^']*)', (\(\) => <[^<>]*>)\],` should do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, I did not know that :-)

Comment: thank you both for the help. I updated the question as I found an edge case and am not sure how to handle it. The original question has been answered and accepted.

Comment: @TomTomSamSam You need a preprocessing step here if the number of spaces is a variable value. Though, you may use a couple of optional groups in the current solution (if you know there can be up to X and no more occurrences of these spaces).

Comment: If you have for example 1 or 2 words, you can Find `\['(\w+)(?: (\w+))?', (\(\) => <[^<>]*>)\],` and replace `export const \l$1$2 $3;` See the matches here https://regex101.com/r/GWo0u3/1